# Diagonalize 3x3 Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations

Question is to Diagonalize a 3x3 matrix:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-4 & -4 & -8 \\
4 & 6 & 4 \\
6 & 4 & 10 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

After personally computing I get the following eigenvalues:

λ= 12
λ = 2
λ = -2

However these do not appear to be the accepted answers according to the solutions. I am fairly new to linear algebra so highly plausible I am doing something wrong. Recently learnt about rational root theorem. Calculations are as follows:

$$
(-4 -6λ) 
\begin{bmatrix}
6-λ & 4 \\
4 & 10-λ \\
\end{bmatrix}
+4
\begin{bmatrix}
4 & 4 \\
6 & 10-λ \\
\end{bmatrix}
-8
\begin{bmatrix}
4 & 6-λ \\
6 & 4 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

= (-4-λ)(λ^2-16λ+44)+4(-4λ+16)-8(6λ-20)
= -λ^3+12λ^2-44λ+48
= (-(λ-12)(λ+2))(λ-2)

λ=12
λ=-2
λ=2

However non of these match the respective values on the diagonal for D according to the prescribed solutions.

I will obviously continue with the rest of the calculations once I can find the correct Eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That $-4-6\lambda$ that you have there is a mistake. It should be simply $4-\lambda$. In the end, you will get the polynomial $-\lambda^3+12\lambda^2-44\lambda+48$, whose roots are $2$, $4$, and $6$. So, these are the eigenvalues of your matrix.

Comment: Oh gosh, typo. My bad.Okay so I am on the right track. Interesting. Are you able to explain as to why I would not merely factorise from = (-(λ-12)(λ+2))(λ-2). Essentially why do I not take 12 and -2? Again I am relatively new to the concept of rational root theorem.

Comment: Because none of the numbers $12$, $2$, and $-2$ is a root of $-\lambda^3+12\lambda^2-44\lambda+48$. The rational roots theorem states (in this case) that the roots of the polynomial are integers that divide $48$. But that doesn't mean that *any* $3$ divisors of $48$ must be roots. You have to check them.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you for that. Would this always be the case when using rational root theorem? I presume if we are able to group then we would take the results after factoring?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Oh and additionally what would happen if you had to have an incredibly large number that had a fair amount of possible rational roots? Would you need to check every single one or would there be a more streamlined process for that as in instead of 48 you had something like 1000048 (Bad example but you get the point)

Comment: What I meant was- Would this be the case for always checking every possible rational root when using the rational root theorem. Additionally doing this would not be applicable if you were able to factorise by grouping - i.e: -(λ-12)(λ+2))(λ-2)

Comment: Yes, you would have to check each of its divisors.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you so much for taking the time to explain this to me. I truly appreciate it :)

Comment: If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: I would be more than happy. I have no idea how to do that :D Edit- I think that is how?

Comment: Yes, that's how. Thank you.